# VS Stopped detecting forms in code? // Value of type 'FormName' cannont be converted to 'Form'

Tags: vb.net

I have an really strange error. I have an sub in a class (API.vb) called OpenApp(). It accepts a form argument (`Public Sub OpenApp(app As Form)`).

Now I have a few other forms called **Settings**, **devtools**, **login** and so on.

When I try `API.OpenApp(Settings)` or `API.OpenApp(devtools)` however, it gives me this error:

> Value of type 'devtools' cannot be converted to 'Form'.'

There is nothing else in the solution declaring devtools, Settings and so on as other things apart from Forms in their classes. Even more, it used to work but it just randomly started doing this.

Edit: As some people asked here's how all of them are declared:

```
 Public Class devtools
```

And settings:

```
 Public Class Settings
```

I think you're getting the point now. Oh, and here's the `API.OpenApp` sub

```
Public Shared Sub OpenApp(app As Form)
    Dim open As Form = OpenProgram(app)
    app.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Perhaps the declarations of Settings, devtools, login, etc?

Comment: They are normal forms, ie. classes. Like if you would go and make some new forms called Settings; devtools; login etc etc

Comment: Perhaps you should share a [mcve]

Comment: @Plutonix Check the edited question.

Comment: Those declarations don't tell us anything.

Comment: There is nothing in your post that shows that `devtools` or `Settings` classes are inherited from `Forms`. If the code does not know that, then of course it will give out an error. If the two classes have methods that return Forms, then use those methods.

Comment: I don't get it. How can I do that? And why did it magically work before? They HAVE an designer form to them btw.

Comment: Why do you need that silly helper class to show a new form in the first place?

Comment: What's the problem with having one? I personally like it better because it's looking more clear, even a bit longer. But, I've tried with Settings.Show() and devtools.Show() and it's not working.

Comment: EDIT: Wait.. I tried it again (.Show()) and.. it.. works? What? I am done. What's the logic?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have pretty much answered it yourself, in your comment. You need to pass an instance of the form to the sub eg:

```
Dim frm as new DevTools
API.OpenApp(frm)
```

Comment: Why isn't directly passing devtools to it not working & why did it work before? Trying the answer out now by the way.

Comment: Update: Nope, not working, the error message is the exact same now.